# Getting random value from array in for loop (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am creating a soundboard that when a button is clicked it plays a random sound. I am trying to do this by creating an array inside a for loop that gets all the mp3 file links (filename) and when a user clicks the button the file name is changes using (Math.floor(Math.random)).

The problem i am having is that it just plays the same sound. It does not play a random sound.

**soundboard.ts**

```
    /* Loop through them, saving their title and sound file */
          for(let link of links) {
            let filename = link.getAttribute("href")            
            let rand = [filename];
            this.sounds.push({
              file: filename,
              rand: rand
            });
          }

    /* Plays the sound */
         play(sound) {     
           sound.rand = sound.file[Math.floor(Math.random() * sound.file.length)];
           console.log(sound.rand)   
           this.media = new Audio(sound.rand);
           this.media.load();
           this.media.play();
         }
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read. You have types in the wrong places. `let rand: any = [filename];` is _terrible_ code. On the other hand, `play(sound) {` could really use a type annotation....

Comment: Anyway, don't you mean `const randomSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sound.file.length)].file;` `this.media = new Audio(randomSound);` Also, why is `rand` initialized to an array with one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a logic error. Based on your problem description, I think you want something like

```
export class Component {
  soundFileNames: string[] = [];

  media?: Audio;

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const link of links) {
      const fileName = link.getAttribute("href");
      soundFileNames.push(fileName);    
    }
  }

  playRandomSoundFile() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * soundFileNames.length);
    const randomFileName = soundFileNames[randomIndex];
    console.log(randomFileName);
    const audio = new Audio(randomFileName);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    this.media = audio;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel it is always better to use "underscorejs" library for these common functionalities. In your case you are trying to get the random value from an array, you can achieve that as below "underscorejs".

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

getRandomElementFromArray (sounds) {
    let randomNumber = _.random(0, sounds.length);
    return sounds[randomNumber];
}
```